# Solaris WANboot & Jumpstart SPARC/x86

Tags: solaris, x86, sparc, jumpstart

I need to setup a Solaris WANboot and a Solaris jumpstart server for both SPARC and x86 architectures. Can I setup both on a single machine (SPARC or x86) or do I need a separate SPARC and x86 machine to jumpstart a SPARC respectively a x86 client?

As far as I know the architecture of a WANboot server doesn't matter, as long as the correct Solaris flash archive is used.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can be set up on a single machine.  You'll need separate binary executables for each ISA, of course, and separate binary boot files for each supported architecture.  The jumpstart/diskless boot server is basically acting as a network file store (albeit with some special, not filesystem protocols), so its architecture can be separate from the client.

The [Custom Jumpstart Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/E23802/preparecustom-56440.html#scrolltoc) should have the information you need.